# Why is the Betti number for a Sphere 0, if the Euler spiral can cut a singular sphere flat?

Tags: algebraic-topology, differential-topology, geometric-topology, betti-numbers

[Wolfram](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/BettiNumber.html#:%7E:text=Betti%20Number%20%20%20surface%20%20%20Betti,%20%202%20%204%20more%20rows%20) has the Betti numbers of surfaces as follows:
**[Surface Betti Number](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oN1Zk.png)  **
cross-cap   1
cylinder    1
klein bottle    2
Möbius strip    1
plane lamina    0
projective plane    1
sphere  0
torus   2

If we were to cut a sphere with a [Euler spiral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_spiral#Normalization_and_conclusion), I could lay the sphere flat. Granted the cut does not meet the beginning and end points, unless we allow more of topological 'holes' rather than 'handles'(or maybe 180 flip our cut and continue back). Can some spaces not be cut as such topologically.
Are these the reasons for the Betti definition? Does it have to do with the contiguity of the cut? What is meant by a 'Noetherian Local Unit Ring'?

Comment: Can you link to the Wolfram page where you found this? Also, what is the definition of (first) Betti number you are using?

Comment: This isn't explained in the linked page, but informally, the first Betti number can be thought of as the maximum number of cuts *along closed simple curves*, i.e. curves which have the same start and end points, and which do not have any other self-intersections. There are much simpler cuts along non-closed curves which leaves a connected space (e.g. cut along the equator, but don't cut all the way).

Comment: Why are you tacking on a question about a 'Noetherian Local Unit Ring' at the end of a geometric topology question?

Comment: The Klein bottle and projective plane entries of this table contradict the formal definition of the first Betti  number of a topological space $X$, namely the rank of the first homology of $X$ with ordinary coefficients in $\mathbb Z$. There is a closely related concept of "$\mathbb Z/2$ Betti number" where those entries make sense. But the link you showed is so completely out of context that I have no idea, and would not want to guess, what the intention was.

Answer (score 4):

Beyond the issues raised in my comments, the title question can be addressed by a few basic observations about topological spaces in general and the sphere in particular.

In a topological space $X$, the existence of an embedded arc (such as the Euler spiral) is irrelevant to determining the first Betti number of $X$, as you hinted in your sentence *"Granted..."* Instead, in a very, very rough sense the first Betti number is concerned with closed curves in $S$, meaning continuous functions $S^1 \mapsto X$ where $S^1$ is the circle.

Narrowing the focus to $X=S^2$, let's consider simple closed curves, each of which is the image of a continuous *injection* $S^1 \mapsto S^2$. Let $C \subset S^2$ be one such curve. According to the Jordan Curve Theorem, $S^2 - C$ is a union of two components $D_1$ and $D_2$. According to the Schönflies theorem, for $i=1,2$ the subspace $C \cup D_i$ is homeomorphic to the standard closed unit disc $\mathbb D^2$ in the plane, with $C$ correspnoding to the boundary circle of $\mathbb D^2$ and $D_i$ corresponding to the interior of $\mathbb D^2$. Clearly you can shrink that boundary circle down to a point, and this can be regarded as *evidence* that the first Betti number of $S^2$ is zero. Beyond that evidence, one can show that any continuous function $S^1 \mapsto S^2$ is homotopic to a constant function.

In general, in any topological space $X$, to say that $X$ is *simply connected* means that $X$ is path connected and every continuous function $S^1 \mapsto S^2$ is homotopic to a constant. One basic theorem of topology is that if a space $X$ is simply connected then its first Betti number is equal to zero. This is one reason why the first Betti number of $S^2$ is equal to zero.

*Warning:* The converse of that theorem is *not true*. The projective plane provides a counterexample to the converse, notwithstanding that table you got from Wolfram: the projective plane is not simply connected because it has an embedded circle which is not homotopic to a constant; but the first Betti number of the projective plane is equal to $0$.

Finally, to expand on one of my comments: the formal definition of the first Betti number of $X$ is the rank of the first homology group of $X$ with $\mathbb Z$ coefficients. From there one can, with some work, write down a formula for the first Betti number of a compact, connected surface with boundary.